# persistence.xml para desenvolvimento e outro para produção?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Tenho meu `persistence.xml` configurado para um banco de dados local.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meubanco"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="usuario"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="senha"/>
```

Acontece que os ambientes de desenvolvimento e produção deverão ter configurações diferentes, pois em produção o BD poderá estar localizado em outro servidor e possuir usuário e senha diferentes.

Como eu faço isso de forma automática?

**Estrutura Multi Tenancy Atual**

*persistence.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="onlinePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>br.com.teste.model.Cliente</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/online"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="senha"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
      <!--Configuracao do Hibernate para MultiTenant-->
      <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA"/>
      <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="br.com.teste.multitenant.SchemaResolver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="br.com.teste.multitenant.MultiTenantProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="2"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.iddle_teste_period" value="70"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="60"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

*MultiTenantProvider*

```
public class MultiTenantProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, ServiceRegistryAwareService  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4368575201221677384L;

    private C3P0ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = null;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void injectServices(ServiceRegistryImplementor serviceRegistry) {
        Map lSettings = serviceRegistry.getService(ConfigurationService.class).getSettings();

        connectionProvider = new C3P0ConnectionProvider();
        connectionProvider.injectServices(serviceRegistry);
        connectionProvider.configure(lSettings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class clazz) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> clazz) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = connectionProvider.getConnection();
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("use " + tenantIdentifier + ";");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ClienteInvalidoException("Cliente inválido!");
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("use online;");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ClienteInvalidoException("Cliente inválido!");
        }
        connectionProvider.closeConnection(connection);
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        releaseAnyConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a real necessidade de realizar de forma automática?

Comment: As estações de trabalho dos programadores possuem seus próprios mysql (localhost). Já no servidor de produção o mysql estará em um outro servidor dedicado. Não quero ter que ficar trocando os dados de conexão sempre que eu tiver que fazer o deploy da aplicação.

Comment: Não sei como funciona sua estrutura de deploy, mas aqui na empresa, alguns arquivos na hora do deploy são desconsiderados na hora de subir pra produção.

Comment: @DiegoSantos Eu tenho um servidor Jenkins que faz uma checagem periódica das alterações e faz o build do projeto. Em algum momento o responsável pela atualização do app pega este build e faz o deploy no servidor produção.

Comment: O `JNDI` é bacana quando você deixa o container criar a conexão, porque simplifica. Neste caso você escreveu código para criar a conexão, então já está pronto para obter os parâmetros de um arquivo de configuração como eu sugeri na minha resposta. Você pode ter um arquivo de configuração com as informações padrão e os devs alteram na sua máquina mas não commitam, ou, melhor, um arquivo `dev` e outro `prod`, sendo que o prod é renomeado e incluído no pacote de distribuição durante a integração contínua enquanto o `dev` é ignorado. Mas eu faria isso com um arquivo à parte do `persistence.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer um acesso a banco dinâmico usando uma arquitetura *multi-tenant*. Há várias saídas.

Pessoalmente eu usaria o Spring para definir diferentes `profiles` como `dev`, `uat` e `prod`.

Então seria possível definir diferentes versões do [`EntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) ou então uma versão única inicializada via arquivos `properties` específicos para cada ambiente.

Uma abordagem mais "manual" é gerar pacotes WAR ou EAR para os diferentes para os diferentes ambientes. Isso é bem fácil com o Maven.

Também seria possível definir diferentes *persistence units* e usar cada um de acordo com o ambiente. Isso pode ser feito ao instanciar o `EntityManagerFactory` através da classe [`Persistence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html), pois há uma versão do método `createEntityManagerFactory` que recebe uma `String`, que é o nome do *persistence unit*.

Outra alternativa é usar o mesmo *persistence unit*, mas passar um mapa com o usuário e senha de cada conexão, carregados de algum arquivo de configuração. Isso pode ser feito através de outra versão do método `createEntityManagerFactory` da classe `Persistence` ou   do método `createEntityManager` do `EntityManagerFactory` já criado.

Comment: Veja no código que postei agora... Já tenho uma estrutura multi-tenant funcionando. Tentei fazer a conexão via JNDI mas acho que conflita com o C3P0... Não sei qual implementação eu poderia usar no lugar de C3P0ConnectionProvider.

Comment: @NilsonUehara Não precisa usar JNDI. É possível passar as propriedades `hibernate.connection.username` e `hibernate.connection.password` no mapa do trecho `connectionProvider.configure(lSettings);`, ao invés de deixar fixo no `persistence.xml`. Você pode, por exemplo, verificar alguma variável de ambiente que diga em qual ambiente você está e então carregar o respetivo usuário e senha de algum arquivo separado.

Comment: Entendi... vou fazer um teste e já posto o resultado.

Comment: Funcionou! Criei <Environment name="db_url"... no context.xml do server e monto os parâmetros antes do connectionProvider.configure(! Valeu @utluiz

Comment: @NilsonUehara Legal, bom saber!

Answer (score -1):

O `persistence.xml` não é um arquivo de configuração de produção. Embora você possa informar todos os detalhes de acesso ao banco de dados neste arquivo, não deveria fazê-lo para uso em produção nem homologação - nestes casos a configuração de acesso ao banco de dados precisa estar aberta ao papel de **"implantador"** do sistema., enquanto o arquivo `persistence.xml` é de responsabilidade do papel **"desenvolvedor"** do sistema.

Ainda que eventualmente a mesma pessoa assuma estes dois papéis, como este arquivo pertence ao conjunto de arquivos de código fonte e é distribuído já configurado, você teria literalmente uma alteração no sistema cada vez que o ambiente mudasse (bancos de dados mudam de lugar, de nome, nome de usuário e senha também mudam).

Se você usa um servidor de aplicativos (`Glassfish`, por exemplo), faça a configuração de acesso a banco usando recurso `JNDI`. Se não, considere colocar as ifnormações de acesso ao banco em arquivo de configuração criptografado.

Comment: Eu uso o Tomcat. Já tentei configurar a conexão via JNDI, mas esbarrei em alguns erros. Talvez por estar usando uma estrutura MultiTentant. Só consegui fazer funcionar colocando todos os dados no persistence mesmo.

Comment: Acho que deveria funcionar mesmo assim. Talvez se você postar os problemas encontrados... De qualquer modo, se você usa integração contínua, pode escrever um script para substituir um arquivo no pacote de distribuição. Eu não faria isso para o `persistence.xml`, mas... fica a seu critério.

Comment: Acho que o problema é que, na configuração atual, estou usando C3P0 (parece que não seria correto usá-lo com Tomcat). Vou postar as classes completas para dar uma idéia mais ampla.